# How can I make a sprite fall from a random x position in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

So what i want to do, is to have my player navigate around objects falling down from the top of the screen. So far, I have the obstacle's random x position, but it wont continue to fall from the top, and will just get stuck. This is what it looks like:
[Black "obstacle" stuck in the top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfP27.png)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

width = 640
height = 480
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Photon')
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')

mspeed = 5
hspeed = 5

hole = pygame.image.load('bHole.png')
sprite = pygame.image.load('photon.png')
spritex = 0
spritey = 0

holex = random.randint(0,260)
holey = 0

while True:
    if holey < 460:
        holey -= hspeed
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(background,(0,0))

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(sprite,(spritex,spritey))

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(hole,(holex,holey))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        spritex -= mspeed

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        spritex += mspeed

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        spritey -= mspeed

    if keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        spritey += mspeed


    if spritex > 620:
        spritex = 620
    if spritex < 0:
        spritex = 0
    if spritey > 460:
        spritey = 460
    if spritey < 0:
        spritey = 0

    if holey < 460:
        holey += hspeed
    elif holey > 460:
        holex = random.randint(0,260)
        holey = 0


    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
    print('PX:', spritex, 'PY:', spritey, 'HX:', holex, 'HY:', holey)
```

Any help would be extremely helpful, as I'm just not sure what to do right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two `if holey < 460:` checks in each iteration of your screen update loop. The first one subtracts `hspeed` and the other adds adds it back — so they cancel each other out and the object gets "stuck" wherever it is.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that!

Comment: 1h4t3l33t5p34k: Yeah, sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes…